# How to randomize deviation of position per instance with Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, random

I have a GeometryNode setup with which I generate instances in X,Y,Z directions and randomly change the angle of each instance. This works fine. Now I would like to control slight deviations of the respective position of each instance X,Y,Z by a random value, but I can't find a way to do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use a "Set Position" node and feed your random values to its Offset. You could also use "Translate Instances". Normally Set Position moves individual points of a geometry but instances will move as "objects", so to speak.

Comment: As @Kuboå says. If you want to use it on instances, you can either use _Translate Instances_ or _Set Position_ node with a _Random Value_ node and get the exact same result. Only if you use a _Realize Instances_ before moving them it will make a difference - because then the instances are turned into meshes and in this case, the _Translate Instances_ node will not work anymore while _Set Position_ now moves the vertices separately (resulting in distorted cubes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *Set Position* (or Translate Instances) node after *Instances on Points*.

[image]
[image]